# Is there a 3-phase to DC converter that draws current proportional to voltage?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, three-phase, ac-dc

Of course, 3-phase alternating current can be converted into a rippling direct current with a 3-phase bridge rectifier.
[image: 3-phase bridge rectifier schematic]

This design only draws current from the two phases with the most voltage differential at any given moment. Therefore, even with a constant load on the DC side, the current drawn from each line doesn't resemble a sine wave, but each phase is at zero current most of the time.
[image: Current drawn by a 3-phase bridge rectifier]

Is there a type of 3-phase to DC power converter that draws current from each phase roughly proportional to voltage, so that the current drawn from each resembles a sine wave? I imagine that such a converter would work by switching between pairs of phases, but I'm not aware of an existing design that does this.

Comment: Electric-Gecko - Hi, Please note that when a post copies or adapts material (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) from elsewhere, that content must be [correctly referenced](/help/referencing). For online content, the source webpage / PDF / video etc. should be named & linked as a minimum (see the rule about references for offline books / articles). Therefore please [edit] your question to add the appropriate source references (source names & links) for those images & remember to include references in future. Thanks.

Comment: Google 3-phase PFC, e.g. https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/us/semiconductor/design-development/referencedesign/detail.RD044.html

Comment: It sounds like you want a power-factor correction circuit, is that correct? In which case, there are many to choose from; what kind(s), if any?

Comment: From where come these waveforms ... I don't understand. fV are the units ...

Answer (score 0):

a rotary converter perhaps [https://en.wikipedia.org
/wiki/Rotary_converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_converter)

[image]

image credit Wikimedia.

Not exactly solid state though.

The solid-state approximation is the 18-pulse rectifier.

Answer (score -1):

Voltages and currents are not right.

Really, you have something like these ...

[image]

And if you want something like "sinusoidal", you have to use a PFC circuit (as already pointed out).

Comment: Sorry. The one I showed was from a simulator.